# Salvage data from fusion drive

Tags: imac, disk-utility, fusion-drive, diskutil

I have a 2015 iMac 27 inch that had a fusion drive. I recently replaced the fusion drive with a SSD drive.

It seems that my iMac had two storages. One is an 128GB SSD drive connected via PCI and a 3TB HDD connected via SATA. These two storages formed a fusion drive. I didn't realize this fact until I replaced the fusion drive.

The problem is I cannot access the data in the HDD. It is natural because the fusion drive was made up of two storages and the SSD storage was erased. However, the other data must exist in the HDD.

Here is a `diskutil cs list` result.

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 8F07F5A3-4B05-41F6-B35D-BF99FD3FFCF6
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         1TB
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         1023620980736 B (1.0 TB)
|   Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume 6A9050D3-A977-4C1A-B5FF-C4137A4F26DE
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume EF2595B2-C272-42E4-9B1C-614192B36B94
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    1
|   |   Disk:     disk1s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     902632128512 B (902.6 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family F3C95F7D-140B-4C8E-BEAE-5C528B7EAFF1
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         None
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume E917FA60-8DD1-435B-A509-A23A606C1A6D
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk2
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          1022999920640 B (1.0 TB)
|           Revertible:            No
|           LV Name:               1TB
|           Volume Name:           1TB
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|           LVG Type:              Sparse
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 695A9E47-5719-4DE5-955B-C621500B3170
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         2746866515968 B (2.7 TB)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 46783A1A-F61F-4807-B0E6-350FD60309CD
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   (No properties)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume F87D50A3-D671-4568-8BB4-354ECE79CF29
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    1
        Disk:     disk3s2
        Status:   Checking
        Size:     2746866515968 B (2.7 TB)
```

The fusion drive used JHFS+, not APFS.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage 1TB                     121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage 1TB                     902.6 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                120.7 GB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS 1TB                    +1.0 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 E917FA60-8DD1-435B-A509-A23A606C1A6D
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.7 TB     disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk3s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                252.3 GB   disk3s4
   5:           Windows Recovery                         518.0 MB   disk3s5

/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk5s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD           999.3 GB   disk5s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk5s3

[keta@iMac /Users/keta]# diskutil mount disk3s2
disk3s2 is a FileVault or Fusion Drive physical volume; use "diskutil coreStorage list" to find its logical volume, which you can then unlock (if necessary) and mount
[keta@iMac /Users/keta]# diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 8F07F5A3-4B05-41F6-B35D-BF99FD3FFCF6
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         1TB
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         1023620980736 B (1.0 TB)
|   Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume 6A9050D3-A977-4C1A-B5FF-C4137A4F26DE
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume EF2595B2-C272-42E4-9B1C-614192B36B94
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    1
|   |   Disk:     disk1s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     902632128512 B (902.6 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family F3C95F7D-140B-4C8E-BEAE-5C528B7EAFF1
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         None
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume E917FA60-8DD1-435B-A509-A23A606C1A6D
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk2
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          1022999920640 B (1.0 TB)
|           Revertible:            No
|           LV Name:               1TB
|           Volume Name:           1TB
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|           LVG Type:              Sparse
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 695A9E47-5719-4DE5-955B-C621500B3170
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         2746866515968 B (2.7 TB)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 46783A1A-F61F-4807-B0E6-350FD60309CD
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   (No properties)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume F87D50A3-D671-4568-8BB4-354ECE79CF29
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    1
        Disk:     disk3s2
        Status:   Checking
        Size:     2746866515968 B (2.7 TB)
```

Is there any good way to rescue data in the HDD? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.